# EPPlus - Why do I get Index out of range when adding new sheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am writing 127 DataTables to an excel workbook using EPPlus using `ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetName");`

```
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws;

        ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(branch); --- Exception thrown here

    }
```

I get an exception at sheet 89 - "Index out of range" but I'm not sure which bounds I'm exceeding. Why do I get Index out of range when adding new sheet?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: First, in Excel indexes start at `1` not `0`, that is a common mistake. But maybe there is an issue with DataTable 89?

Comment: Just in case (should not be the same error) be careful of max length of a worksheet name. If your branch name is long, you may have duplicated names because of troncation and it may result in thrown exception